# Excel: How to sum up cells that are next to cells of the same number

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I have two columns of data. The first column contains categories in the form of numbers, and the second column contains data that I want to sum up. So if you see the attached picture, I'd like to sum up all the red, green and blue into a single row, because each group shares the same numbered neighbor in the left column.

I tried using SUMIF but that doesn't seem to be designed for this.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely barking up the right tree with SUMIF.

Where:
=SUMIF(VALUES for condition, Condition, NUMBERS to Sum)

Take a look at the attached example I put together which I believe is what you are after:

[SUMIF Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJitA.png)

Remember to lock the appropriate cells, in my case the VALUES for condition and NUMBERS to sum so that I can drag the formula which updates the Condition cell.

Comment: This seems perfect for SUMIF. Note (purely personal choice) I always like to use SUMIFS regardless of the number of parameters - I prefer the Summed column to always be the first parameter, and it's far easier to add more parameters in the future

Answer (score 2):

You could use column C to calculate a cumulative sum, and reset whenever the value in column A changes.  So, you would:

- set C1 to `=B1`
- set C2 to `=IF(A1=A2, C1+B2, B2)`
- copy C2 down to the end of the range

Now you can apply conditional formatting on column C to highlight the final sum when the *next* cell in column A is different, or you could make column D where:

- set D1 to `=IF(A1=A2, "", C1)`
- copy D1 down to end of the range

This gives just the final sums, and empty cells for everything else.  You can hide column C, since it's an intermediate result.

Comment: This seems like a lot more work than is needed compared to a SUMIF

Comment: But it is more efficient, since a naive SUMIF must examine the entire data range, resulting in O(N^2) time complexity.  By contrast, this is O(N).

Comment: How is SUMIF O(N^2)? isn't it linear and based solely on the number of distinct categories? Also your formulas are assuming sorting, which by definition isn't in linear time. Although lets be honest, if OP was to base the answer on time complexity I don't think excel is the best medium in the first place xD

Comment: I'll give you an upvote though - I agree that is an important point for some tasks

Comment: It's linear for each criteria you select on.  Or rather, linear for each individual SUMIF.  So I should say O(N*M) where M is the number of SUMIF calls.  And I said O(N^2) because the naive approach is to use a SUMIF for every row.  So, if you aren't sure where your data is partitioned, and just pepper SUMIFs around, you could have poor performance unless Excel is doing something clever like caching results for equivalent statements.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - I assumed OP had a summary or a list of distinct values. Sumif on every row would definitely not be a good idea